# Cross products of each row of a matrix with the corresponding row of another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have the following 2 matrices

```
A <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, c(
  5, 1, 2, 
  3, 1, 5, 
  5, 1, 3, 
  7, 2, 8, 
  2, 4, 2
))

B <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, c(
  2, 1,
  3, 5,
  1, 4,
  3, 3,
  3, 4
))
```

and I want to create an array

```
arr <- array(NA, dim = c(ncol(A), ncol(B), nrow(A)))
```

to store the cross product of row `i` of matrix `A` with the same row `i` of matrix `B`. For example, slice 2 of `arr` would be

```
A[2, ] %*% t(B[2, ]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   15
[2,]    3    5
[3,]   15   25
```

Using a for loop, I can do

```
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
  arr[, , i] <- A[i, ] %*% t(B[i, ])
}
```

Or using an `sapply` function

```
temp <- sapply(1:nrow(A), function(i) A[i, ] %*% t(B[i, ]), simplify = FALSE)

arr <- array(unlist(temp), dim = c(ncol(A), ncol(B), nrow(A)))
```

I am wondering if there is more clever way using matrix products or built-in functions in this case. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think "outer" is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try base R option with `mapply` + `tcrossprod` like below

```
array(
  mapply(tcrossprod, asplit(A, 1), asplit(B, 1)),
  c(ncol(A), ncol(B), nrow(A))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is great. Exactly what I need and also in base R.

Answer (score 2):

**1) einsum** Using einstein summation notation

```
library(einsum)

arr1 <- einsum("ij,ik->jki", A, B)
identical(arr1, arr)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) Khatri Rao Product** The product in question is related to the column-wise Khatri Rao product sometimes just called the Khatri Rao product.  Note that Matrix comes with R so it does not have to be installed.

```
library(Matrix)

arr2 <- array(KhatriRao(t(B), t(A)), c(ncol(A), rev(dim(B))))
identical(arr2, arr)
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) Kronecker Product**  If X and Y are matrices with the same number of columns and I<sub>m</sub> and I<sub>n</sub> are column vectors of ones with m = nrow(X) and n = nrow(B) elements then we can use the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618580/khatri-rao-product-as-a-matrix-multiplication) X ⊙ Y = (X ⊗ I<sub>n</sub>) ∘ (I<sub>m</sub> ⊗ Y) that expresses the Khatri Rao columnwise product ⊙ in terms of the Kronecker product ⊗ and Hadamard, i.e. element-wise, product ∘ to derive another base solution.

```
arr3 <- array( (t(B) %x% rep(1, ncol(A)) ) * 
               ( rep(1, ncol(B)) %x% t(A)), c(ncol(A), rev(dim(B))))
identical(arr3, arr)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The package looks very interesting.